# Gluon (mobile) and SPI (service provider interface)

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile, gluonfx, gluon-desktop

I am experimenting using Gluon (both native and mobile) with GeoTools.

GeoTools loads object factories via the service provider interface (SPI) in Java (specifically by using META-INF/services files).

So far my experiments with using META-INF/services files to load factory classes into a Gluon app (either native or mobile) haven't worked. The object factories fail to load with a message like:

```
org.geotools.util.factory.FactoryRegistry scanForPlugins
[SUB] WARNING: Can't load a service for category "CRSFactory". Cause is "ServiceConfigurationError: org.geotools.api.referencing.crs.CRSFactory: Provider org.geotools.referencing.factory.ReferencingObjectFactory could not be instantiated".
```

I am guessing that I can't actually use the META-INF/services files approach with Gluon, as scanning jars for plugins won't be supported in a native/mobile app.

Is that correct? Or is there something I am missing?

thanks

Tried using SPI via META-INF/services files. Was expecting the service provider factories to work. They didn't.

Comment: Have you tried running the native agent (`mvn gluonfx:runagent`), it should find the  META-INF/services files and add it to the configuration files for the native image. Then build the image again.

Comment: I am not sure I am following here.

Comment: I am not sure I am following here.

I currently make my native image by doing: gluonfx:compile link package install nativerun

Are you suggesting I do something else?

Also I am wondering if the problem is that my META-INF/services files are not being copied into the native image resources, so I need a resourceList pattern?

Comment: Yes, see https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_goals and run `mvn gluonfx:runagent` before building the native image.

Comment: Thanks Jose (sorry no accent on the e :-().  That idea worked perfectly. It picked up all the SPI stuff.